# System.AccessViolationException when calling Print() on a FlowDocumentScrollViewer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, access-violation

We have a WPF application targeting .NET Framework 4.

Here is a short explanation about the actions that cause the exception:

1) The application receive a string with Xaml content from the db.

2) The content is converted to a FlowDocument via a converter (XamlReader.Parse method).

3) The document is presented to the user in a FlowDocumentScrollViewer.

4) The user prints the document which calls the Print() method on the FlowDocumentScrollViewer object.

5) The application crashes.

It's important to notice that the exception only occurs on computers inside a specific organization. we never had this exception elsewhere.

We tried to replace the direct call to Print() with other implementations (e.g. calling the the printDialog manually) and still no luck.

The only thing that sort of worked (and also not permanently) was to install all the windows features under .net 3.5.1 on the specific computer.

Here is a summary of the trace:

```
Framework: v4.0.30319 System.AccessViolationException 
in- MS.Internal.Printing.UnsafeNativeMethods.PrintDlgEx(IntPtr) 
in- MS.Internal.Printing.Win32PrintDialog.ShowDialog() 
in- System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Did u check this link? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cf744c83-fd7e-434c-b160-3f076d7491bf/systemaccessviolationexception-attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Our application has a right to left flow direction.
Apparently removing the code FlowDirection="RightToLeft" from the window resolves this issue.